# what is quadruple in IC gates

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates

What is quadruple in integrated circuit gates? Is it just about 4 gates inside the IC or anything else more special?

Comment: What does the datasheet show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is usually an IC with 4 of the same gate inside it sharing a common \$V_{CC}\$ and GND.

The datasheets sum this up pretty well. Here is a quad NAND gate pinout:

[image]

Notice that there is one set of power connections and 4 identical gates.

Comment: You will also find the terms "double", "triple", and "hex" (and others), meaning two, three, or six identical gates in one package.

Comment: And "octal", meaning eight. For example in buffers used for data and address busses. cc: @PeterBennett

Comment: @dipylon Feel free to accept this answer if you thought it answered your question the best :)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, yes, it refers to the number of gates in a chip.

A "Quad 2-input NAND gate" (74xx00) has 4 gates in it, each with 2 inputs.

If there is a 4 input or 4 bit gate it is normally referred to as such - a "4-bit ripple counter" or a "4-input OR", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Quadruple, or more commonly just "quad", means 4 of something in a package.  For example, the 7400 is a "quad NAND gate" chip, and the LM324 a "quad opamp".  Yes it really is that simple.